How to best use IX as a return stack
I'm new to Z80 assembler and am porting a Forth interpreter from a J1 stack machine to a Z80 based board. The Z80 port uses SP for the data stack, and IX for the return stack.
The port uses a normal CALL instruction, which puts the return address in the data stack. The called subroutine first moves the return address to the return stack using HL as working register:
pop hl              ; hl <- return address
dec ix              ; push address into return stack
ld  (ix), h
dec ix
ld  (ix), l

After the routine do his thing, the return is made by popping HL from the return stack then jumping thru HL:
ld      l, (ix)     ; pop return address from return stack
inc     ix
ld      h, (ix)
inc     ix
jp      (hl)        ; return via jump

What is the optimal way to do this?

I'm curious about the design decision that led you to use sp as the data stack rather than the return stack.

@JeremyP. Forth is defined to have two stacks: one for data (passing parameters, work operands, return results) and other for return addresses (which also works as a limited auxiliary stack). As data stack is more used than the return stack, SP is better. I'm following the guide in "Moving Forth", by Brad Rodriguez (https://www.bradrodriguez.com/papers/moving1.htm)

If you're using CALL, your interpreter is subroutine-threaded. The paper explicitly says that the PSP is used more than the RSP in ITC and DTC, but not in STC. With STC, you probably don't want to use the hardware stack as your parameter stack.

My intuition would be to use IX for the data stack, so that the (IX+d) addressing can refer to the data elements, but I don't know if that is a typical pattern for Forth.

@DaveTweed. The data stack is much more used than the return stack, so it makes sense to use SP as data stack.

@RalfKleberhoff. From Forth.org: A stack is not an array ... an ANSI standard program cannot make any assumptions about where the stacks are located or how they are implemented  In particular, the J1 CPU uses shift registers for stack implementation.

Every time you know address of caller code in advance, you could try the following:
;procedure call
ld hl,return_address
jp procedure
;...
procedure: ;prologue
dec ix
ld  (ix), h
dec ix
ld  (ix), l
...
;epilogue same as yours

This way you would save 7 clocks using jp instead of call for procedure entry (ld hl is same as pop hl).
Otherwise not much place to optimize since (ix) operations are very slow.
More clock savings traded for yet bigger size:
;procedure call
dec ix
ld (ix),return_addr_hi
dec ix
ld (ix),return_addr_lo
jp procedure
...
procedure: ;no prologue
...
;epilogue same as yours

Here you save additional 4 cycles by not loading constant to HL. ld (ix),immediate still take 3 cycles to load immediate from memory -- same as 3*2 cycles for immediate loads in ld hl.
Another possibility for leaf procedures:
ld hy,h ;copy HL to IY, since IX holds return stack pointer
ld ly,l ;
...
jp (iy) ;return

If you can know in advance that the procedure to call is leaf, just
ld iy,return_address
jp procedure
;...
procedure: ;no prologue
...
jp (iy)

If you carry no data in alternative register set of Z80, you can think of placing return address there:
 exx
 ld hl,return_address
 jp procedure
return_address:
 exx
...
procedure:
 exx
...
 exx
 jp (hl)

You don't need two exxs in the caller code when additionally no information is passed between procedures in HL
